# array.sort() - Method isn't working as it should

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display a Array of names in a table. ist like a timetable and i have a sort-button because if i want to add a new Student, the Student should be classified at the right place.
My Array contains this values

- Benj
- Zebra
- Yves
- Anna

but if i press the sort button the output is like this

- Zebra
- Yves
- Anna
- Benj

That dosent make sense ist not ascending and not descending

Here is the code

```js
function sort(){
  students.sort();
    for(var i = 0;i<students.length+1;i++){
        if(i!=0){
          alert(students[i-1].innerHTML);
         <!table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML=students[i1].innerHTML;>
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: please add `students`.

Comment: Why *Anna* before *Benj*?

Comment: @Mamun - that's what OP GETS, not WANTS

Comment: thank you bravo so clear ist an Array of cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to sort the rows of an existing table - here's a better way

```js
document.getElementById('sort1').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let tableBody = document.querySelector('#table>tbody');
  let rows = [...tableBody.querySelectorAll('#table>tbody>tr')];
  rows
    .sort((a, b) => a.cells[0].textContent.localeCompare(b.cells[0].textContent))
    .forEach(row => tableBody.append(row));
});
document.getElementById('sort2').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let tableBody = document.querySelector('#table>tbody');
  let rows = [...tableBody.querySelectorAll('#table>tbody>tr')];
  rows
    .sort((a, b) => a.cells[2].textContent.localeCompare(b.cells[2].textContent))
    .forEach(row => tableBody.append(row));
})
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Delta</td>
      <td>Alpahbetically 4th</td>
      <td>Rank 2nd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bravo</td>
      <td>Alpahbetically 2nd</td>
      <td>Rank 1st</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Charlie</td>
      <td>Alpahbetically 3rd</td>
      <td>Rank 4th</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alpha</td>
      <td>Alpahbetically 1st</td>
      <td>Rank 3rd</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="sort1">Sort by name</button>
<button id="sort2">Sort by rank</button>
```